# Why this shadowing when dealing with a dataset?

Tags: dataset

I have a dataset which I use as "dsall" and a function keylist (just for my convenience, nothing spectacular):

```
keyList[ds_Dataset] := Keys@ds[[1]] // Normal // Flatten
```

Now I get the shadowing warning as shown in the picture. I get this only sometimes, even when starting from a clean kernel. Is there any idea where this comes from and how to avoid it? There is no symbol "data" in my context??[image]

Comment: I am afraid that you did not give us enough information to reproduce your problem. Indeed, I can't reproduce it on my end. Any more details you could share?

Comment: This is essentially the same problem as reported in [Streaming\`LazyList\`Testing may have a leak](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88393/142).  Voting to close as a duplicate.