# Operating on a dataset named "data" triggers an error message

Tags: dataset

**Update**: With thanks to the editor, it was made clear to me that this is due to a bug in some packages autoloaded during some operations on Dataset expressions. Nothing to do with the name of the Dataset per se.

'mecium

==========

1) Define a dataset named "data"

```
data = Dataset[{{1,2}, {1,3}, {2,2}}]
```

2) Now apply a GroupBy (or GatherBy, or SortBy) operation on it:

```
GroupBy[data, First]
```

3) Be puzzled by this response or laugh at my rampant stupidity...

```
>> data::shdw : Symbol data appears in multiple contexts {Streaming`LazyList`Testing`, Global`}; definitions in context Streaming`LazyList`Testing` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions...
```

4) Be twice puzzled: all 3 operations work fine if the dataset has a different name (i.e. other than "data").

I am seeing this in MMA 10.2 on OSX 10.10.4
Can anyone replicate this behavior, or suggest a workaround?

RTMF'ing failed. This breaks code that I do not want to rewrite.

Paranoid addendum: should I avoid using "data" as a symbol name?

Cheers!

Comment: geeeeeeeeeeeez!

Comment: The result of the `GroupBy` operation is actually correct.  The message `data::shdw` is a known V10.2 bug discussed in [(88393)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88393/142).  See that question for a work-around.  Voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: While the message is "interesting" and clearly a duplicate, it should be noted that your `Dataset` is not "destroyed": `Normal@GroupBy[data, First]` gives the expected `<|1 -> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}}, 2 -> {{2, 2}}|>`. Also, it is still accessible via ``Global`data``, even if it is less convenient.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I will mark the question closed as a duplicate. After reading the referenced discussion (88393), I am not knowledgeable enough to understand if using another symbol for my dataset (i.e. not "data") avoids the problem or simply hides it from view. @rcollyer: thank you for the correction. I see that the wording of the title is poorly chosen, and may lead others to misinterpret the bug.